# Cannot explain runtime Error

Tags: remix, error

When I use the variable minimum in the require statement

```
require(msg.value >= minimum, "Below Minimum");
```

I get the below error in Remix. However, if I hardcode the require statement with 0 instead of minimum everything works.  Why?

> transact to SendContractEther.sendEtherToContract errored: VM error:
> revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
> Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the
> value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the
> transaction to get more information.

I am sending Ether to contract King from contract SendContractEther.

Thank you for an explanation for this behavior.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract King {

  uint public minimum;
  address payable public owner;

  constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;  
    minimum = 0;
  }

  receive () external payable {
    
    require(msg.value >= minimum, "Below Minimum");
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
  
  }

}
```

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract SendContractEther {
    
    address payable public contractAddress ;
    
    // Assign the address of the Contract
    constructor(address payable _contractAddress) payable {
        contractAddress = _contractAddress;
    }
    
    function sendEtherToContract() external payable {
        
        contractAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question!

The gas-stipend for functions `receive` and `fallback` when executed as a result of transferring ETH to the contract from another contract (i.e., not from an externally-owned account) is 2300.

In your case:

```
require(msg.value >= minimum, "Below Minimum");
owner.transfer(msg.value);
```

- The cost of reading the storage variable `minimum` is 800 gas
- The cost of reading the storage variable `owner` is 800 gas
- The cost of executing an external function-call via `transfer` is at least 800 gas (depending on the amount being transferred, as well as the balance of each side)

The gas required for evaluating the expression `msg.value >= minimum` (as well as for reading the local variable `msg.value` itself) is negligible, but as you can see, you are already above the gas-stipend even without it, using at least 2400 gas.

Thus, replacing the storage variable `minimum` with a hard-coded `0` may get you well below the gas-stipend (using around 1600 gas) and resolve the problem.

You can verify this by transferring ETH to that contract from an externally-owned account, where no gas-stipend applies, and see that it completes successfully despite the storage variable `minimum` being used (provided that you transfer an amount equal to or larger than `minimum`).

Alternatively, you can rename function `receive` and then call it directly from the other contract:

```
contract King {
    ...

    function test() external payable {
        require(msg.value >= minimum, "Below Minimum");
        owner.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}

contract SendContractEther {
    ...
    
    function sendEtherToContract() external payable {
        King(contractAddress).test{value: address(this).balance}();
    }
}
```

Since no gas-stipend applies here., executing `sendEtherToContract` should complete successfully.

Comment: Thank you goodvibration for that detailed explanation.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Another solution that I just tried is to replace contractAddress.transfer(address(this).balance);  with contractAddress.call{value: address(this).balance, gas: 3000000}(""); and ensure that there is enough GAS allocated in MetaMask.